# How to break out of loop for blank input

Tags: c, scanf

How do I break out of this while loop if the user just presses enter without typing anything.

```
int main()
{
while(1){
    int integer;
    printf("enter integer:");
    scanf("%d",&integer);
   }
    return 0;
   }
```

Comment: not possible with `%d`.

Answer (score 2):

You can't. `scanf` is a horrible function and should be avoided (in particular, you should never use it for user input).

The easiest way to get user input working is to make sure all input is through `fgets` (which reads a whole line). You can then analyze that line, convert it to a number (e.g. with `strtol`, `strtod`, `sscanf`, ...), or do whatever you want with it.

Here's an example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    while (1) {
        char buf[200];
        int integer;

        printf("enter integer: ");
        fflush(stdout);
        if (!fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin)) {
            /* input error or end of file reached */
            break;
        }
        buf[strcspn(buf, "\n")] = '\0';  /* remove trailing newline, if any */

        if (buf[0] == '\0') {
            /* empty line */
            break;
        }

        sscanf(buf, "%d", &integer);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to me...

1. Take input as a string
2. IF inputString equals to lineBreak
3. THEN break
4. OTHERWISE convert it into integer

   ```
   int main()
   {
        while(1)
        {
            int integer;
            char input[1024]; 
            printf("enter integer:");
            fgets (input, sizeof (input), stdin);
            if (strcmp (input, "\n") == 0)
                break;
            integer = atoi(input);
        }
        return 0;
    }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible,
Initialise the value of integer with something that is not allowed in input
For eg if the input takes positive integers ,I initialise integer with -1

```
int main()
{
while(1){
    int integer=-1;

    printf("enter integer:");
    scanf("%d",&integer);
if(integer==-1)
break;
   }
    return 0;
   }
```